# Minify images using webpack encore

Tags: symfony, webpack, symfony4, webpack-encore

I've been trying to configure Encore for a new project. The CSS and JS work perectly but I want to go a bit further with the images. So far I'm only creating a copy of my images in my build respecting the same architecture :

```
//file: webpack.config.js
let Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
// the project directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // the public path used by the web server to access the previous directory
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // uncomment to create hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment to define the assets of the project
    .addEntry('js/app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('js/admin', './assets/js/admin.js')
    .addStyleEntry('css/app', './assets/css/app.scss')
    .addStyleEntry('css/bootstrap-datepicker', './node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css')

    //assures compatibility in case of same file name
    .configureFilenames({
        images: '[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]',
    })

    // uncomment if you use Sass/SCSS files
    .enableSassLoader(function (options) {
        // https://github.com/sass/node-sass#options
        options.includePaths = ['assets/compass_src'];
    })

    // uncomment for legacy applications that require $/jQuery as a global variable
    .autoProvidejQuery()

    // show OS notifications when builds finish/fail
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

And I'm managing my images like that :

```
//file: app.js
const imagesContext = require.context('../images', true, /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg|webp)$/);
imagesContext.keys().forEach(imagesContext);
```

I tried using glob to minify (lossless compression) my images but haven't been successful.

**How can I minify my images ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [image-webpack-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-webpack-loader) plugin and add it to your `webpack.config.js`:

```
.addLoader({
   test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
   loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
   options: {
      bypassOnDebug: true, //only minify during production
      plugins: [
          {removeTitle: true},
          {convertColors: {shorthex: false}},
          {convertPathData: false}
         ]
      },
  })
```

To manage your images, you can make an `image.js` file and load your images as such:

```
require.context('../images', true, /\.jpe?g$|.png$|.svg$|.gif$/);
```

More information can be found [here](https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader)

Answer (score 2):

I use [image-minimizer-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-minimizer-webpack-plugin) in Symfonyv6 webpack encore.

```bash
yarn add -D image-minimizer-webpack-plugin sharp
```

```js
// webpack.config
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require("image-minimizer-webpack-plugin");

Encore
        // directory where compiled assets will be stored
        .setOutputPath('public/build/')
        // COMPRESS IMAGES
        .addPlugin(new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
            minimizer: {
                implementation: ImageMinimizerPlugin.sharpMinify,
                options: {
                    encodeOptions: {
                        // Your options for `sharp`
                        // https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-output
                        jpeg: {
                            quality: 72,
                            mozjpeg: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }))

        // IMAGES
        .copyFiles({
            from: './assets/images',
            // optional target path, relative to the output dir
            // to: 'images/[path][name].[ext]',

            // if versioning is enabled, add the file hash too
            to: 'images/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]',

            // only copy files matching this pattern
            pattern: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|webp)$/
        })
        // ...
```

Reference Links:

1. [image-minimizer-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-minimizer-webpack-plugin)
2. [Managing CSS and JavaScript](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html)
3. [Adding Custom Loaders & Plugins](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/custom-loaders-plugins.html)

Here I use sharp. You can use any (imagemin | @squoosh/lib | sharp | svgo ) all config is same.